# Create json Array in java Servlet using JSON

Tags: java, json, servlets

I want to Create json array like this to use jquery datatable plugin with java servlet

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Garrett Winters",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$170,750",
      "start_date": "2011/07/25",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "8422"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its Very easy actually. Use Google `gson.jar` **Either** you download From Here 
[Download Google GSON Jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/g/Downloadgson222jar.htm) **OR** add dependencies(**if Your Project is Maven**) to your `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and try this Link [GSON Serializer Example](http://www.javacreed.com/gson-serialiser-example/)

> **Note** :- This is just a reference code. You can Implement at your own way as per your Need. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Create a POJO which represents your JSON object. Top object containing list of second object. Use jackson or xstream to marshal Java object into Json and write the json string onto servlet response.